# How come “What if no one would be allowed to post....” doesn’t sound right?

Tags: conditionals

What mistake I have made in this sentence? It sounds wrong:

> **What if no one would be allowed to post ...**

Let's say people are allowed to post pictures on the website and I want to talk about the past (e.g. idea): **What if no one would be allowed to post pictures on the website.**

Comment: It doesn't sound _wrong_, but it is not a statement about the past. It can apply to the future (i.e. "what will happen if the decision would be taken to ...") or to an alternate reality ("what would be happening now if the decision was taken in the past to ...")

Comment: It does sound wrong.

Comment: 'What if none were allowed' sounds better, to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re talking about a hypothetical ***past***, you would say:

> Q: What if no one **had been allowed** to post on the website?
>
> A: If no one **had been allowed** to post on the website, no one would have visited it.

If you’re talking about a hypothetical ***non-past***, you would say:

> Q: What if no one **were allowed** to post on the website?
>
> A: If no one **were allowed** to post on the website, no one would visit it.

Of course, *be allowed* is like *be able* and *can/could*, so that’s also:

> Q: What if no one **could** post on the website?
>
> A: If no one **could** post on the website, no one would visit it.

A rule of thumb is not to use *will/would* in the “if” part (except in those rare cases that it means permission, like *if you will please take your seats*).